# Change Query to include derived data rather than hard-coded data

Tags: sql, sql-server, interpolation

I am using SQL Server 2012.
I have the following query which is pulling various fields from several different views. The query then dynamically interpolates three different values every time there is a new group in the ContentSetName column. Note also the value of Cover occurs only once per group. This is all working fine, but I now need to alter the hardcoded value being used for report_SSRS in the ContentSetName column to use a dynamically derived value.
Please see this previous Stackoverflow post regarding this query

[Dynamically interpolate extra rows in SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763803/dynamically-interpolate-extra-rows-in-sql-query)

Since then the query has evolved to this:

```
WITH Data AS
(   SELECT b.ReportHeading1, 
            bb.ReportHeading1 as RepHeading1,
            bb.ReportHeading2 as RepHeading2,
            bb.ReportHeading3 as RepHeading3,
            p.DisplayOrder, 
            p.MemberCode,
            m.PortfolioGroupCode as DistGroup,
            m.MemberCode as Packgroup,
            g.purpose,
            p.PortfolioGroupID as pid,
            m.PortfolioGroupID as mid,
            lb.value as repset,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.portfoliogroupid ORDER BY p.DisplayOrder)
    FROM    [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioGroupMemberFlattened] p
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioBase] b
                ON b.PortfolioBaseID = p.PortfolioGroupID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioBase] bb
                ON bb.PortfolioBaseID = p.MemberID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioGroupMember] m
                 on m.MemberID = p.PortfolioGroupID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioGroup] g
                ON g.PortfolioGroupID = m.PortfolioGroupID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioBaseLabels] lb
                on p.MemberID = lb.PortfolioBaseID
                WHERE     m.PortfolioGroupCode like '%_Dist%'
                and (g.Purpose like '%_ind' or g.Purpose like '%_group')
                and lb.Label = '$repset'

       )
SELECT
d.repset,
d.DistGroup,
d.Packgroup,
t.ContentSetName,
    CONCAT(d.pid,'_',d.DisplayOrder,'_',t.ContentSetName,'_') as DistributionName,
        CONCAT(d.RepHeading1,'_',d.RepHeading2,'_', d.RepHeading3) as DistributionCustom,
    'False' as IsForFunctionalGroup,
    'True' as IsLandscapePageNum,
    1 as NumOfCopies,
    d.purpose as RecipientCode,
    d.ReportHeading1 as RecipientFullName,
    d.MemberCode as ReportingEntityCode,
    'Daily' as RunEvent
    FROM    Data d
        CROSS JOIN 
        (   VALUES
                ('Cover_SSRS'),
                ('Separator_docx'),
                ('Report_SSRS')
        ) t (ContentSetName)
WHERE   d.RowNumber = 1
OR      t.ContentSetNAme != 'Cover_SSRS'
```

This produces the following sample result set.

```
repset  DistGroup   Packgroup   ContentSetName  DistributionName    DistributionCustom  IsForFunctionalGroup    IsLandscapePageNum  NumOfCopies RecipientCode   RecipientFullName   ReportingEntityCode RunEvent
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Cover_SSRS  11221_5251_Cover_SSRS_  Test Trust - Third Generation__ FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test1   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Separator_docx  11221_5251_Separator_docx_  Test Trust - Third Generation__ FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test1   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Report_SSRS 11221_5251_Report_SSRS_ Test Trust - Third Generation__ FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test1   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Separator_docx  11221_5679_Separator_docx_  Test Trust - Fourth Generation__    FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test2   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Report_SSRS 11221_5679_Report_SSRS_ Test Trust - Fourth Generation__    FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test2   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Separator_docx  11221_5727_Separator_docx_  The Test Family Trust One__ FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test3   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Report_SSRS 11221_5727_Report_SSRS_ The Test Family Trust One__ FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test3   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Separator_docx  11221_5779_Separator_docx_  The Test Family Trust Three__   FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test4   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Report_SSRS 11221_5779_Report_SSRS_ The Test Family Trust Three__   FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test4   Daily
DVAStandard Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_2  Cover_SSRS  11222_5309_Cover_SSRS_  John P. Smith_Custodian for Jordan V. Smith UTMA_   FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  John Smith  test5   Daily
DVAStandard Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_2  Separator_docx  11222_5309_Separator_docx_  John P. Smith_Custodian for Jordan V. Smith UTMA_   FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  John Smith  test5   Daily
DVAStandard Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_2  Report_SSRS 11222_5309_Report_SSRS_ John P. Smith_Custodian for Jordan V. Smith UTMA_   FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  John Smith  test5   Daily
```

Here is the desired result set

```
    repset  DistGroup   Packgroup   ContentSetName  DistributionName    DistributionCustom  IsForFunctionalGroup    IsLandscapePageNum  NumOfCopies RecipientCode   RecipientFullName   ReportingEntityCode RunEvent
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Cover_SSRS  11221_5251_Cover_SSRS_  Test Trust - Third Generation__ FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test1   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Separator_docx  11221_5251_Separator_docx_  Test Trust - Third Generation__ FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test1   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  DVAAnnual   11221_5251_DVAAnnual_   Test Trust - Third Generation__ FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test1   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Separator_docx  11221_5679_Separator_docx_  Test Trust - Fourth Generation__    FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test2   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  DVAAnnual   11221_5679_DVAAnnual_   Test Trust - Fourth Generation__    FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test2   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Separator_docx  11221_5727_Separator_docx_  The Test Family Trust One__ FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test3   Daily
DVAAnnual   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  DVAAnnual   11221_5727_DVAAnnual_   The Test Family Trust One__ FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test3   Daily
DVAValues   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  Separator_docx  11221_5779_Separator_docx_  The Test Family Trust Three__   FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test4   Daily
DVAValues   Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_3  DVAValues   11221_5779_DVAValues_   The Test Family Trust Three__   FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  Test Trusts test4   Daily
DVAStandard Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_2  Cover_SSRS  11222_5309_Cover_SSRS_  John P. Smith_Custodian for Jordan V. Smith UTMA_   FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  John Smith  test5   Daily
DVAStandard Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_2  Separator_docx  11222_5309_Separator_docx_  John P. Smith_Custodian for Jordan V. Smith UTMA_   FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  John Smith  test5   Daily
DVAStandard Wendy_Jones_Dist    Wendy_Jones_Pack_2  DVAStandard 11222_5309_DVAStandard_ John P. Smith_Custodian for Jordan V. Smith UTMA_   FALSE   TRUE    1   JonesWendy_ind  John Smith  test5   Daily
```

The difference between the current and desired result sets is that instead of the static value 'Report_SSRS' for the third interpolated row I want to pull the value of d.repset which in this example varies between DVAAnnual, DVAValues, and DVAStandard.

I am also concatenating the d.repset column (currently as t.contentsetname) within the DistributionName column and want to use the the value of d.repset there instead of the hardcoded value of Report_SSRS.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just change the query to:

```
WITH Data AS
(   SELECT b.ReportHeading1, 
            bb.ReportHeading1 as RepHeading1,
            bb.ReportHeading2 as RepHeading2,
            bb.ReportHeading3 as RepHeading3,
            p.DisplayOrder, 
            p.MemberCode,
            m.PortfolioGroupCode as DistGroup,
            m.MemberCode as Packgroup,
            g.purpose,
            p.PortfolioGroupID as pid,
            m.PortfolioGroupID as mid,
            lb.value as repset,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.portfoliogroupid ORDER BY p.DisplayOrder)
    FROM    [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioGroupMemberFlattened] p
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioBase] b
                ON b.PortfolioBaseID = p.PortfolioGroupID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioBase] bb
                ON bb.PortfolioBaseID = p.MemberID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioGroupMember] m
                 on m.MemberID = p.PortfolioGroupID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioGroup] g
                ON g.PortfolioGroupID = m.PortfolioGroupID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [APXFirm].[AdvApp].[vPortfolioBaseLabels] lb
                on p.MemberID = lb.PortfolioBaseID
                WHERE     m.PortfolioGroupCode like '%_Dist%'
                and (g.Purpose like '%_ind' or g.Purpose like '%_group')
                and lb.Label = '$repset'

       )
SELECT
d.repset,
d.DistGroup,
d.Packgroup,
t.ContentSetName,
    CONCAT(d.pid,'_',d.DisplayOrder,'_',t.ContentSetName,'_') as DistributionName,
        CONCAT(d.RepHeading1,'_',d.RepHeading2,'_', d.RepHeading3) as DistributionCustom,
    'False' as IsForFunctionalGroup,
    'True' as IsLandscapePageNum,
    1 as NumOfCopies,
    d.purpose as RecipientCode,
    d.ReportHeading1 as RecipientFullName,
    d.MemberCode as ReportingEntityCode,
    'Daily' as RunEvent
    FROM    Data d
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   VALUES
                ('Cover_SSRS'),
                ('Separator_docx'),
                (d.repset)
        ) t (ContentSetName)
WHERE   d.RowNumber = 1
OR      t.ContentSetNAme != 'Cover_SSRS'
```

The difference is instead of using:

```
CROSS JOIN 
(   VALUES
        ('Cover_SSRS'),
        ('Separator_docx'),
        ('Report_SSRS')
) t (ContentSetName)
```

It has changed to

```
CROSS APPLY 
(   VALUES
        ('Cover_SSRS'),
        ('Separator_docx'),
        (d.repset)
) t (ContentSetName)
```

By using CROSS APPLY, instead of CROSS JOIN you still have access to all the fields in the query.

Comment: I tried it but get this error Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to varchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: ammending this line with convert fixed it convert(varchar(max),lb.value) as repset